# C# how to convert SQL query to Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

I have a List of the following type:

```
public class V_Articles
{
    public string code{ get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string shortDescription { get; set; }
}
```

I have a string variable containing the name of one of its properties:

```
string fieldName = "description" (or "code" or "shortDescription ")
```

Given an already populated list, is there a way to make a generic lambda expression?

```
List<V_Articles> list = Get_List(popolate the list);
List<V_Articles> list_2 = list.Where(k => k.{value of fieldName} == 'towel').ToList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build the `Func<>` as an `Expression<>` tree:

```
string fieldName = "description";
string value = "towel";

var k = Expression.Parameter(typeof(V_Articles), "k");

var filter = Expression.Lambda<Func<V_Articles, bool>>(
    Expression.Equal(
        Expression.Property(k, fieldName), 
        Expression.Constant(value)
    ), 
    k
);
```

and then it depends on what exactly `list` is in your snippet. If it's an `IQueryable<>` like a `DbSet<>` you can use the Expression directly and execute your filter code directly on the DB

```
List<V_Articles> list_2 = _context.V_Articles.Where(filter).ToList();
```

otherwise you might need to turn the `Expression` into a `Func` first:

```
List<V_Articles> list_2 = list.Where(filter.Compile()).ToList();
```

Comment: Your solution works perfectly.
I gave the right answer to Good Night Nerd Pride because he answered for first

But I do not know which solutions is faster

Comment: @Vez using expressions [is faster](https://www.palmmedia.de/Blog/2012/2/4/reflection-vs-compiled-expressions-vs-delegates-performance-comparison) than reflection. Especially if you are able to cache the compiled `filter` in a static member of your class (e.g. a `Dictionary` that maps a property name to a compiled expression). You should mark this answer as accepted, simply because it's the better one. No hard feelings ;)

Answer (score 1):

[Sandeep Bhat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77357469/1025555) is probably the way to go for performance reasons, but if you feel so inclined you can also use reflection to solve this dynamically:

```cs
var propName = "code";
var list_2 = list.Where(k => k.GetProperty<string>(propName) == "towel");

public static class Extensions {
    public static T? GetProperty<T>(this object obj, string prop) {
        var t = obj.GetType();
        var p = t.GetProperty(prop)
            ?? throw new MissingMemberException($"Property '{prop}' not found on type {t.FullName}.");
        var v = (T?)p.GetValue(obj);
        return v;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
List<V_Articles> list_2 = list.Where(k=> k.code == 'towel' || k.description == 'towel' || k.shortDescription == 'towel').ToList();
```

Comment: This does something different to what OP asked. `k.code == "towel"` and `k.code == "towel" || k.description == "towel" || k.shortDescription == "towel"` produce different results unless you can guarantee that the value `"towel"` occurs only in one column. And OP didn't say that